# Check the type of an input in pyO3 Rust

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

Could someone give a full/working example of a function in pyO3 that takes a single input, and returns `true/false` depending on whether the input has type `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`?

I'm aware that pyO3 has [`is_instance`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/types/struct.PyAny.html#method.is_instance), but that seems to require having an object that represents a type.  I know about [`get_type`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/marker/struct.Python.html#method.get_type), but that assumes you already have an object of the right type, which gets me confused.

Comment: Not too sure what you want exactly, if you want a Python-level typecheck you need to get a handle on the type you're looking for using [`import`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/marker/struct.Python.html#method.import) and something like [`getattr`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/types/struct.PyAny.html?search=import#method.getattr) to dereference the object you're looking for, then `is_instance` to do the actual check.

Comment: This can be simplified if pyo3 (or some other package) provides a Rust level version (then you can use `is_instance_of`, or even just request the rust-level type and let pyo3 do the typechecking) but unless someone provides an equivalent to [`rust-numpy`](https://github.com/PyO3/rust-numpy) that seems unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for this input.  Could anyone give a concrete example? (of a function that takes a Python object as input and returns true/false depending on whether the Python object has a given type, e.g. `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`)